# Couldnt get connectionjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, база-данных

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");//This s wat actually i did for connection
    System.out.println("Driver Loaded Succesfully");
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Unable to Load Driver!!!");
}
String url = "jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/";
String dbName = "namebase";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String userName = "login"; 
String password = "pass";
try {
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);

conn.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Couldnt get connection");
    }
    }
}
```

Не конектится к базе.
Так же в базе есть схема и возможно ли что из-за нее трабла?

> Couldnt get connectionjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Распечатайте стектрейс в catch. Скорее всего он содержит четкое описание ошибки.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.lang.Throwable.setStackTrace(Throwable.java:620)
 at TestDriver.main(TestDriver.java:27)

Comment: Если уж перехватываете Exception, то выводите их:
System.out.println("Couldnt get connection: " + e)

Проблема может быть не в коде, а в самой базе. Она у вас вообще работает? Доступна?


Comment: работает и доступна. Подключаюсь к ней через mysql query browes, все работает

Comment: Jar-ка с классом драйвера к проекту подключена?

Comment: @Bezyshodnyi Во-первых, это только часть стектрейса. Во-вторых, у вас есть ошибка и номер строки, в которой она происходит. Почему бы не подумать, что идет не так.

Comment: ошибка здесь:

> Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

надо грузить `mysql` драйвер, тот который вы создаете ниже в коде: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: если вы про mysql connector то он имеется подгруженный в библиотеке.

Comment: Явно, что ошибка в том, что не возможно найти класс com.mysql.jdbc.Driver! Он должен быть в библиотеке JDBC, скорее всего в этой: 

> если вы про mysql connector то он
> имеется подгруженный в библиотеке.
> 

Откройте эту библиотечку, посмотрите, есть ли в ней такой класс com.mysql.jdbc.Driver?

Comment: http://pic2net.ru/5250584731

http://pic2net.ru/5951584731 вот class path было по дефолту

http://pic2net.ru/6982584731

Comment: Так, драйвер есть... А, банально, библиотеку в Class Path проекта добавили?

Comment: Хорошо,в class path есть, а сама [среда разработки знает путь][1] к этой библиотеке (напр. в Eclipse - Build Path->Libraries)?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591505/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver

Comment: Так, значит с драйвером все хорошо! Может попробовать без создания инстанса класса:

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance() 

Будет тот же exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каменты жгут... Неужели здесь не осталось людей способных подцепить JDBC драйвер MySQL?

Для того, чтобы код работал нужно [выкачать JDBC драйвер MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) и положить в свой CLASSPATH (надеюсь, что такое CLASSPATH объяснять не надо)

**P.S.** А это что за хрень?

```
try 
{    
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    System.out.println("Driver Loaded Succesfully");
}
```

Вы хотя бы понимаете что это означает?! Это означает что вы зачем-то подгружаете JDBC-ODBC драйвер. Какое это имеет отношение к MySQL?

Comment: да полез сразу на хэшкод.... стыдно, простите, сначала надо было туториалы нормально почитать. асел я, что сказать. Спасибо большое за ответ. Скачал книгу Хорсмена 2 том и начал изучение, и больше не буду беспокоить никого глупыми вопросами.